# Why can't nobody log into my Terraria server using my external IP?

Tags: technical-issues, terraria, hosting

OK. So this has been going on for me for about 3 months, since I moved. Before I moved, I used an Ethernet internet to launch servers. Everything worked PERFECTLY. But now, I use a Wireless internet and did the exact same thing as I did before, but NOPE. Doesn't work. I have searched countless hours on the internet for the solution, NOTHING helped. I have port-forwarded successfully and when I check on "canyouseeme.org" if port 7777 (the port I port-forwarded and am using) is open, and it is open. I have allowed the port through my firewalls, tried disabling them, nothing worked. I also set up a static IP, but that didn't help much. So I ask, what do I do, to make it so that ANYBODY can connect to my terraria server with my external IP? Just saying this now, I can connect to my own server using localhost, my local IP adress or 127.0.0.1 easily. But the external IP is crucial to my friends, so that they can connect. Help, please? :(

Comment: By "internet" you mean router I suppose? If you changed routers and it stopped working after that then the router is misconfigured. Routers are a tricky thing and it's a matter of trial and error when doing server setups. When I was setting up my server I could not configure it either. Your options are trying with other games to see if it's a Terraria-only issue; keep disabling everything you can, i.e. "debugging" the router; or use a Virtual Lan. As JanGret said, Hamachi is an option, I also used Tunngle back when it was on beta and with better results than with Hamachi.

Comment: I have indeed tried this on other games (such as Minecraft) and counter-strike:Source, but didn't work. I guess i'll have to try out Tunngle.

Comment: I've tried Tunngle, didn't help at all. It's just a chat type system, like teamspeak. I've port-forwarded 11155 and tried launching a terraria server with it, didn't work, unless i need to use some other IP than my external ip. Do I?

Comment: No i't not a chat system, it's a Virtual Network system, when you connect to a room, you are in a LAN with the people of such rooms, you will need your friends to connect with Tunngle too, so they are in the same network as you. I don't know about the configuration required with Terraria, according to [this](http://www.tunngle.net/community/topic/123401-how-to-play-terraria-online-using-tunngle/) it's pretty easy to setup, but you'll have to learn how to use Tunngle. Back when I used it with Starcraft 1 I didn't even had to port-forward anything because Tunngle uses Upnp.

Comment: Ok I watched the video in the link I posted, it explains how to join and host servers, it should be easy to setup a game once you watch it. What you need to share is your Tunngle IP, just in case.

Comment: Aahhh, I guess i did need to use an IP that isn't my external one. I used my Tunngle IP and it appeared to work for me. When my friend is able, we'll test it out. But it seems like it's working fine. :)

Comment: Yep. Worked fine. I guess from now on I'll just have to use Tunngle.

Comment: Good to know, yeah it's not a solution but a decent workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The things I thought about:

For port forwarding: Have you checked if you entered the right IP for your computer? My computer had a different IP after switching from W-LAN to Ethernet

It could also be that in addition to your software firewalls somehow the windows included firewall is maing problems. Maybe check this too if it allows for Terraria.

A work around could be using a virtual LAN service to start the games. Hamachi is one possibilty.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, JanGret, nice answer!

Comment: Yes, the IP is correct, and Windows firewall allows terraria, too. I guess my only bet now is to try out a virtual LAN service.